# Preferred Method of PHP Byte Encoding

Tags: php

I am writing a web app for a company that wants to host the app on its servers. I want to protect the source code for two reasons. The first is the obvious closed source business model. The second is source code protection. I don't want them to be able to edit the source code (They aren't competent). I've looked into things like the Zend Encoder. What have you used? Are there free options? Do they run on Windows and/or Linux?

Comment: To paraphrase an answer on a similar question: Don't protect your source code with obfuscation, protect it with a contract. Just make sure your contract with them spells out what they can and cannot do with your code, and throw in a clause about how much you'll charge them to fix issues stemming from their meddling with your code.

Comment: Agreed. Protected your IP through a contract. Protect the app by developing it externally and under version control. If they edit the source and break it, offer to restore the app to the state in which it was supplied.

Answer (score 0):

I chose to go my selling a support service. All help (FAQs, tutorials, support) is not shipped with the product. To login to the support server, they must provide a company ID (via POST), Thanks for the tips.